# Publish WPF Project from Command Line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, command-line, msbuild

I have a solution containing only one WPF project, when i try it create a package from this project using msbuild(commandline), i got the error

> The target "Package" does not exist in the current project.

Troy hunt discuss about this problem in this link [Why the target "Package" does not exist in the current project.](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/10/why-target-package-does-not-exist-in.html), but it does not help me, maybe because i am using a WPF project and that example is for a web project.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to create the publish the project using

msbuild MyProject.csproj /t:**package** /p:configuration=release

The above line works perfectly fine for web projects but for windows project it should be

msbuild MyProject.csproj /t:**publish** /p:configuration=release

I hope it saves someone's time